# AWS CodeBuild fails DOWNLOAD_SOURCE step due to invalid S3 ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to implement AWS CodePipeline to demonstrate continuous integration for my PHP project in Docker. Problem is when building source using CodeBuild I am getting this error:

> CLIENT_ERROR: invalid S3 ARN for primary source and source version
>   master

Thing is, I am not using S3 for my primary source, but rather CodeCommit repo, which I mirrored from my BitBucket. I have checked [Troubleshooting CodeBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html) article, but it doesn't have description for this error. My CodeBuild sevrvice role policy allows all actions to S3 too.

EDIT: CodeBuild project was created as part of CodePipeline and does work if it is run by pipeline, only gives me this message if I try to test it and run it in isolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was this Build project created as part of a CodePipeline? If so, builds for the project should be initiated by CodePipeline not CodeBuild directly as the source for the CodeBuild project will be set as CodePipeline and CodePipeline should feed the artifact to CodeBuild which is always as an S3 arn.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you very much, project is part of pipeline.